# MIPS Memoy layout: to whom it is relevant

Tags: embedded, mips, mips32

I have been reading about MIPS Memory layout:
https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2004/fall/cs301/notes/notes/node12.html
As an application programmer, I don't see where the above memory mapping can be relevant to me when i write my application programs. 
Is it instead relevant to system programmers, Compiler/Assembler writers when they generate the binary addresses in their codes. If so, is there any wisdom behind the  choice of the above interlaced addresses?

Thank you

Comment: The map as supplied is the memory map *an application sees* - It doesn't tell a system programmer anything.

Comment: Thank you @tofro. I meant by system programmer in his case: compiler/linker coders. They have to take the above mempry mapping when resolving the different memory addresses

Answer (score 0):

The map as supplied is the environment your application is "thrown into". It does indeed have some important information:

- Applications need to be linked to start at address 0x400000
- Code + Data + Stack cannot exceed 2 gigabytes
- In case your stack overflows, it will run into your data, not your code (which would be entirely different if the stack grew from 0x400000 downwards, for example)
- Usable addresses for your program are limited to the range of 0x400000 to 0x7ffffff, so a program cannot occupy more than 2GB

As the map shows the memory layout *for an application*, thus most probably virtual addresses, it wouldn't be very useful for a systems programmer.